# Using SharpScript with Unity

Tags: servicestack

In search for a scripting language for my Unity application I came across SharpScript and the example project (https://github.com/ServiceStack/script-unity) that worked fine. However the example project is more than 2 years old so the language and its implementation had went a long way since then.

So I have updated all the SharpScript related dlls to their latest versions to get the latest version and now my project still works in the editor but it stopped working when built with IL2CPP + .Net4.x Unity settings. The error I'm getting upon the start is this:

```cs
NotSupportedException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager::get_AppSettings
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Net45PclExport.RegisterLicenseFromConfig () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.DynamicNumber.TryParse (System.String strValue, System.Object& result) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp+Reader.AddToken (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] tokens, System.String s) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp+Reader.ReadToken () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp+Reader.Read () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.ScriptLisp.Configure (ServiceStack.Script.ScriptContext context) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.ScriptContext.Init () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ScriptExample.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.LicenseUtils' threw an exception.
  at ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.DynamicNumber.TryParse (System.String strValue, System.Object& result) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp+Reader.AddToken (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] tokens, System.String s) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp+Reader.ReadToken () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp+Reader.Read () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.ScriptLisp.Configure (ServiceStack.Script.ScriptContext context) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.ScriptContext.Init () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ScriptExample.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig' threw an exception.
  at ServiceStack.DynamicNumber.TryParse (System.String strValue, System.Object& result) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp+Reader.AddToken (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] tokens, System.String s) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp+Reader.ReadToken () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp+Reader.Read () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.Lisp..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.ScriptLisp.Configure (ServiceStack.Script.ScriptContext context) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.ScriptContext.Init () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ScriptExample.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Script.Lisp' threw an exception.
  at ServiceStack.Script.ScriptLisp.Configure (ServiceStack.Script.ScriptContext context) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Script.ScriptContext.Init () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ScriptExample.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

All info I have found online regarding this error says that maybe adding the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` assembly would fix it, but it did not work in my case: neither the `ConfigurationManager` class is being seen by the IDE, nor adding the

```xml
 <assembly fullname="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" preserve="all"/>
```

line into the `links.xml` has any effect.

All in all, I can't use SharpScript in the project because of that -- being up-to-date with the latest development is a very important point which doesn't hold here.

The versions of the assemblies that I've used are these:

```
servicestack.common.5.11
servicestack.interfaces.5.11
servicestack.text.5.11
system.buffers.4.5.1
system.configuration.configurationmanager.5.0.0
system.memory.4.5.4
system.numerics.vectors.4.5.0
system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.5.0.0
system.threading.tasks.extensions.4.5.4
```

So from my understanding what happened here is that SharpScript configuration became coupled with the configuration provider and now it has a hard dependency on `ConfigurationManger` which somehow is impossible to get working in a modern Unity application build. There were [similar](https://forum.unity.com/threads/issue-with-system-configuration-configurationmanager-get_appsettings-on-ios.1026877/) problems with an [AWS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1262) that never found a real solution.

#### So the question is:

How do I make the latest version of SharpScript work in a Unity application build? If it's impossible to do then SharpScript is not usable as a scripting language for Unity games and that would be really sad, considering that it looks very promising and well put among its alternatives.

**PS:** I tried seeking help on the official forum but my account does not get approved. I don't get any notice but as I understand it -- it's because I don't have a commercial license. I'm only making games so I'm not going to use anything else from ServiceStack than SharpScript and it's license is said to be free for use in any commercial and closed-source applications. However the current situation effectively prevents me or possibly anyone who makes Unity games from doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This runtime Exception occurs when trying to access the .NETs `ConfigurationManager` class which is now being caught from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/d5b29a3443efb6ef3daa675cf2458db86395c78c).

This change is available from the latest v5.11.1+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Awesome! Just checked, everything works! Thanks!